Trouble building KVM from source for Ubuntu 22.04. section size must match the kernel's
I'm trying to build KVM and I'm having trouble figuring out where I went wrong. It builds fine, I'm 99% sure I'm cloning the correct kernel tag in git, but it doesn't load.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, with HWE. Here's the relevant info:
user@computer$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
user@computer$ hwe-support-status --verbose
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2027.
user@computer$ uname -a
Linux computer 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And no SecureBoot:
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled

I followed the KernelGitGuide to clone a copy of Jammy and I targeted the tag: Ubuntu-hwe-6.5-6.5.0-28.29_22.04.1 as this is the one that matches my uname -a output and is HWE. My clone command:
git clone --branch Ubuntu-hwe-6.5-6.5.0-28.29_22.04.1 --depth 1 git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/jammy kernel

To build the kernel I run:
cp /boot/config-6.5.0-28-generic ./kernel/.config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic/Module.symvers ./kernel/
make -C ./kernel/ prepare
make -C ./kernel/ modules_prepare
make -C ./kernel/ M=arch/x86/kvm/

I install the built files to /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic/updates/mykvm Then I run sudo depmod -a 6.5.0-28-generic, sudo rmmod kvm-intel kvm, and sudo modprobe kvm-intel

modprobe output:

$ sudo modprobe kvm-intel
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Exec format error


Full dmesg error:

module kvm: .gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Start Over: Use Browser Tabs Tab 1:BuildYourOwnKernel,  Tab 2: KernelGitGuide.  Switch as needed. Note that this process should be followed with each Ubuntu Release, and if you do it multiple times, you wont need to install the tools again.

Thank you but I don't want to build the whole kernel. I'm trying to make a simple mod to KVM and building the entire kernel for that is unnecessary. I'm using the running kernel's config from /boot and the build of KVM works without error. I inspected the generated kernel module (.ko files) and it seems the problem is in the vermagic. For whatever reason the version 6.5.13+ is sneaking in and I can't figure out where it's coming from. As a first step, I'm simply attempting to build an unmodified KVM and get it loaded. If I can do that, I should be able to modify it no problem.

That's your choice, but following the links I provided is the official documentation ensures you have an avenue to report a bug if necessary.

Oh alright. I guess I get what you're putting down. If I clone that tag and follow those steps and have the same issue then that's just a bug to report. Fair enough.

So I tried the building the whole kernel thing. That came with a host of other nightmares that I likely could have figured out - but then I found this: https://imil.net/blog/posts/2022/build-a-single-in-tree-linux-kernel-module-debian--clones/ - the fact that building a single unmodified kernel module has this much headache associated with it is mind blowing.

The answer turned out to be here: https://imil.net/blog/posts/2022/build-a-single-in-tree-linux-kernel-module-debian--clones/
I'll detail the steps below since I targeted linux 6.5.0 instead of 5.4.0 like the article (though that is literally the only change to the commands).

Install sources. apt-get source linux-source- does NOT work apparently.

sudo apt install linux-source-6.5.0 linux-headers-$(uname -r)
tar jxvf /usr/src/linux-source-6.5.0.tar.bz2
cd linux-source-6.5.0


Build

cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make oldconfig scripts prepare modules_prepare
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers .
make -C . M=arch/x86/kvm


Test

sudo rmmod kvm-intel kvm
sudo insmod arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
sudo insmod arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko

After these tweaks to my build system I had KVM loading without the original error. If you see errors unknown symbols in dmesg, make sure your loading kvm.ko first and then kvm-intel.ko.
